# How to wait for API to finish creating and writing an audio file locally before uploading it to S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm basically calling an API to generate a TextToSpeech audio file on the local filesystem before reading it and uploading it to an S3 bucket. I'm using [elevenlabs-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elevenlabs-api) package.

As it stands, the code is failing because it takes a few seconds for the file to be created and written completely. (more if the file is larger)

I tried using `setTimeout()` and it absolutely worked, but it's not efficient nor dynamic plus the API request kept timing out even though the audio file was being created on local disk. This is not an ideal solution.

```
async function s3upload() { }

setTimeout(s3upload, 5000)
```

I think it has to do with async functions and await/promise but to be honest I don't fully understand the concept yet. Still new to Node/Express.

As you can see below, I have set `await` on both `TextToSpeech()` and `fileContent` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
exports.tts = async (req, res) => {
    
    // TextToSpeech() is responsible of creating the file and writing it
    let audio = await TextToSpeech(apiKey, text, voice_id, fileurl)
    console.log(`Success, Audio saved as: ${fileName}`)

    const spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint('endpoint')

    const s3 = new aws.S3({
        endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWSACCESSKEYID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRETACCESSKEY,
    })

    const fileContent = await fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\User\\Projects\\backend\\public\\upload\\text_to_speech\\' + fileName, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(data)
    })

    const upload = s3.putObject({
        Bucket: 'bucket',
        Key: `${fileName}`,
        Body: fileContent,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return console.log('AWS ERROR', err)
    });

}
```

Comment: Please include a link to the documentation and/or code for the `TextToSpeech()` function that you are using.  We need to see what options it has for communicating back when it's done.

Comment: @jfriend00 here's the package I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/elevenlabs-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are out of luck with that API as it is.  That API does NOT tell you when it's done.  It tells you when it has gotten the initial response from the `api.elevenlabs.io` server, but not when it's done writing to the output file.

The code in it's one source file can be modified to this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');


const elevenLabsAPI = async (apiKey, text, voice_id, file_name) => {
  try {
    var voice= "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/"+voice_id +"/stream";
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: voice,
      data: { text },
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'audio/mpeg',
        'xi-api-key': apiKey,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      responseType: 'stream'
    });
    await pipeline(response.data, fs.createWriteStream(file_name));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

And, then your `await TextToSpeech(apiKey, text, voice_id, fileurl)` will wait for the file to be written.

In your code, there is no point to using `await` with `fs.createReadStream()`.  That function does not return a promise (it returns a stream) so using `await` with it does nothing useful.

Comment: Should I be modifying the package source code directly like that? Or should Implement your function manually in my controller?

Comment: The API request's status is also saying `(canceled)` after a while even though it is writing the file and uploading it to S3. Console error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: timeout of 60000ms exceeded`

Comment: If you want to keep it as a package, then you can fork it into your repository and fix it.  You could even propose a fix to the original author.  You can also just copy the function into your own project, though it will then be up to you to maintain it.

Comment: I don't know anything about the timeout.  You'll have to debug why the API is doing that.  You can pass a longer client-side timeout to `axios()` if that's where the issue is coming from.